# Which design pattern to reduce a collection of entities?

Tags: php, design-patterns

I need to remove some entities from a collection of entities, to do so, I call 4 services one after the other to remove the entities who don't match some filters.

```
class MainService
{
    public function removeEntities($collection)
    {
        $collection = $this->subServiceA->removeEntities($collection);
        $collection = $this->subServiceB->removeEntities($collection);
        $collection = $this->subServiceC->removeEntities($collection);
        $collection = $this->subServiceD->removeEntities($collection);

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

I think that decorator, chain of responsibility or observer can handle this case but I don't know which one suit it the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple queue style approach should work for this.

```
interface IEntityWorker {
    function process($item);
}

class Queue {
    protected $workers = [];

    public function registerWorker(IEntityWorker $worker) {
        $this->workers[] = $worker;
    }

    public function process($item) {
        foreach ($this->workers as $worker) {
            $item = $worker->process($item);
        }
        return $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about something close, finally i don't need a design pattern. thank you